# Can't connect cells in a markdown table

Tags: html, markdown

I have a markdown table of six columns and want the entry of the first row to go over the full length of all columns, just like below.

[tried solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4vpL.png)I already tried that way but the text just jumps into another column.

[failing result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjhZT.png)

Is there any way to create it like that **without** doing it in HTML?

Comment: Markdown syntax is simplified and does not allow you to describe this complexity of your desire.

Comment: Also possible using [pandoc grid tables](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-grid_tables)...